# Reference list from file for citations

Tags: bibtex, subfiles

I try to automate part of the work linked to a set of figures.
The figures are generated from data files, and I would like to add the source of the data for each figure, from a file containing the citation key.

Here is a MWE focussing on this citation feature:

```
% !TEX program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8

\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{filecontents}{biblist1.tex}
ref1,ref2
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblist2.tex}
ref2,ref3
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{sample.bib}
@article{ref1,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}
@book{ref2,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
@misc{ref3,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html"
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Test document.

% Here is the test:
Sources set 1 are: \cite{\input{biblist1}}
Sources set 2 are: \cite{\input{biblist2}}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

`\input{biblist1}` print `ref1,ref2` in the pdf as expected.

`\cite{ref1,ref2}` creates the correct references in the PDF.

`\cite{\input{biblist1}}` generates an error:

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 46.
<inserted text> 
\fi 
<*> TestBib.tex

The file ended while I was skipping conditional text.
This kind of error happens when you say `\if...' and forget
the matching `\fi'. I've inserted a `\fi'; this might work.

! Emergency stop.
<*> TestBib.tex
```

Any idea on how I should load the files?

Comment: The default file extension in the argument of `\input` is `.tex`, not `.txt`. More importantly, the argument of `\cite` (as defined by the `cite` package) is not expanded; it’s supposed to be a list of keys to BibTeX entries.

Comment: @Mico I changed to .tex in the MWE.

My level in *tex do not allow me to understand the expanding issue you refer to.

Answer (score 4):

`\input` is not the right tool; you can use `catchfile` instead to save the file contents in a macro that you can then expand at the right time.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-biblist1.tex}
ref1,ref2
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-biblist2.tex}
ref2,ref3
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ref1,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}
@book{ref2,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
@misc{ref3,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html"
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\newcommand{\filecite}[1]{%
  \CatchFileDef{\filecitetemp}{#1}{\endlinechar=-1 }%
  \expandafter\cite\expandafter{\filecitetemp}%
}

\begin{document}

Test document.

% Here is the test:
Sources set 1 are: \filecite{\jobname-biblist1}
Sources set 2 are: \filecite{\jobname-biblist2}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

I added `\jobname-` as a prefix in order not to clobber my files, it's not required for the solution.

[image]

A simpler version with `expl3` (no `\expandafter`, but the idea is the same).

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-biblist1.tex}
ref1,ref2
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-biblist2.tex}
ref2,ref3
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ref1,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}
@book{ref2,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
@misc{ref3,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html"
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% internal version of \cite
\cs_new_eq:NN \togh_cite:n \cite
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \togh_cite:n { V }

\tl_new:N \l_togh_cite_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\filecite}{m}
 {
  \tl_set_from_file:Nnn \l_togh_file_tl { } { #1 }
  \togh_cite:V \l_togh_file_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Test document.

% Here is the test:
Sources set 1 are: \filecite{\jobname-biblist1}
Sources set 2 are: \filecite{\jobname-biblist2}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, and thanks to you I understood the point of the `\jobname`.
Still a small issue remaining. It seems that when reading the file, lualatex sees a space at the end (while the tool I'm using do not intend to print it).
I guess this comes from encoding issue.
Is there a way to trim the last character from the file? BibTeX really do not like this space.

Comment: @Togh `\CatchFileDef{\filecitetemp}{#1}{\endlinechar=-1 }`

Comment: The issue comes from my files on the real work case, and is not replicated with this mwe as  `filecontents` does a great job. Your answer fully comply with the question I asked.
I generate these files from Julia's `write()` function.
If you think this should require a new question or be dealt on the Julia side, don't hesitate to tell.

Comment: Perfect! This `\endlinechar=-1` is the solution to my encoding issue.